# How can I charge and output audio from iPhone 5 in a car?

Tags: audio, charging, iphone

I want to charge my iPhone 5 and listen to the music using AUX in my car. How can I do this using one cable? I have such a cable for my iPhone 4. Is there any good option for iPhone 5?

Comment: Could you provide a link or picture of your current cable? I'm having trouble following how it works?

Comment: @bassplayer7 I've used this one: http://www.amazon.com/Kensington-Charger-Audio-iPhone-including/dp/B0031U1AU0/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1357694115&sr=8-3&keywords=kensington+iphone5+car+charger+aux

Answer (score 2):

My 2013 Ford Ranger (the T6 international version) has an audio system with a USB port on it, and it plays audio through that regardless of whether it is the old 30-pin connector or a Lightning connector on the other end. When I plug in my iPhone, it says "Connecting iPod" on the audio screen. It also supports audio over Bluetooth.

(When saying "in a car", please be a little more specific about the car and/or its audio system. They are all different)

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase a roughly $30 [adapter from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD823ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter?fnode=3a) to use your old cable with your new iPhone 5. This is a 30 pin to Lightning adapter.

Comment: Does it support charging and audio output at the same time? I've seen a comment somewhere that it does not do at the same time.

Comment: @Chang, good question. I actually don't have one so I can't test it, unfortunately. I am assuming it would. I know the 30 pin does, but again, can't say for sure on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use an aux cable which is small enough to fit next to the 30pin cable to  charge the ipod or lightning to charge my iphone 5s. But that still is not 1 cable. I had to search hard for an aux cable which was small enough. Most aux cables are to thick to fit next to my 30pin adapter. Lightning is much thinner so that would fit easily.

Answer (score -1):

There's more expensive [$30 option on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SU3N87Q)
And ten time cheaper [slew of cables offered on aliexpress for $3](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2-in-1-3-5mm-Jack-Audio-AUX-Cable-and-USB-Charging-Cable-for-iPhone-7/32779087358.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.yGvbQG#j-rpbk-from-otherseller)